# why does not my query work in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle-apex

This is my query but when I run this in oracle apex it gives me the following error:

```
delete from 

(select ename,e1.store_id,e1.sal as highest_sal 
from
employees e1 inner join 
(select store_id,max(sal) as sal
 from employees
 group by store_id
) e2
on e1.store_id=e2.store_id
and e1.sal=e2.sal
order by store_id) s

where rowid not in
(select min(rowid) from s
group by highest_sal);
```

The output is:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_210200", line 673
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_210200", line 659
ORA-06512: at "APEX_210200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 1829


4. (select store_id,max(sal) as sal
5.  from employees
6.  group by store_id
7. ) e2
8. on e1.store_id=e2.store_id
```

When I run the code in parentheses, which has the alias s alone, it runs without any problems, but when it is placed in this code, it gives an error

**updated**: My goal is to first group the data according to store_id and get the maximum sal in each, and join it to the main table itself where sal and store_id are the same, and display its name, which The resulting table is called s. Then I want to remove the duplicate rows from the table (which have the same sal) and to do this we group according to highest_sal and select the least rowid between them, and remove those rowId that are not in the subquery. As a result, non-duplicates are obtained. (This is a trick to remove duplicate lines.)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please [edit] the question and give an English description of the problem (as we currently have to try and reverse engineer the problem from the code) and include a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the table, the `INSERT` statements for some sample data and your expected output after the `DELETE` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to want to delete all rows with the highest `sal` for each `store_id` grouping except for the row in each group with the lowest `ROWID`.

You can do that with analytic functions. Either:

```sql
DELETE FROM employees
WHERE  ROWID IN (
  SELECT ROWID
  FROM   (
    SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY store_id ORDER BY sal DESC) AS rnk,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY store_id ORDER BY sal DESC, ROWID ASC)
             AS rn
    FROM   employees
  )
  WHERE  rnk = 1
  AND    rn > 1
);
```

or:

```sql
DELETE FROM employees
WHERE  ROWID IN (
  SELECT ROWID
  FROM   (
    SELECT sal,
           MAX(sal) OVER (PARTITION BY store_id) AS max_sal,
           MIN(ROWID) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY sal)
                      OVER (PARTITION BY store_id) AS min_rid_for_max_sal
    FROM   employees
  )
  WHERE  sal = max_sal
  AND    ROWID != min_rid_for_max_sal
);
```

Or, from Oracle 12, with row limiting clauses in a correlated sub-query:

```sql
DELETE FROM employees e
WHERE  ROWID IN (
  SELECT ROWID
  FROM   (
    SELECT sal
    FROM   employees x
    WHERE  e.store_id = x.store_id
    ORDER BY sal DESC
    FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
  )
  ORDER BY ROWID
  OFFSET 1 ROW FETCH NEXT 100 PERCENT ROWS ONLY
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees (ename, store_id, sal) AS
SELECT 'A', 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 1, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E', 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'F', 2, 2 FROM DUAL;
```

All delete the `f` row.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=86cf3c96dd7754846e6b9ca2bf332b55)*

Comment: I updated my post and wrote my main purpose and one thing is  I do not want to solve with analytic functions, but I want to know what the problem is with my code. sorry for the delay.

Comment: @aforz `DELETE FROM` a subquery with multiple joins is not valid syntax; that is what is wrong. You need to `DELETE FROM employees WHERE ...` and do the filtering in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I have the where clause at the end of the code. One problem is that the subquery s itself works, but it gives an error when I put parentheses around it and give it the alias s. That is, it runs without aliases

Comment: @aforz As I said, `DELETE FROM` a subquery with multiple joins is not valid syntax; that is what is wrong.

Comment: I have added an update that does not use analytic queries.